# How do I insert an SD card into an Azpen A727 tablet?

Tags: sd-card

I have an Azpen A727 tablet and I want to put an SD card into it.

I have looked all over the internet and the device itself and found nothing.

Does the tablet support SD card?

Comment: Did the tablet not come with User Manual or Device Manual? Use it or ask the manufacturer to obtain another copy to get your answer. I don't know about tablet but for phones, the slot is usually in the compartment covered by battery (you got to remove the battery first) or at the left or right side of the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You should find a slot for Micro SD up to 32 GB on the left side. You can see it in this photo:

[image]

<sup>(from https://youtu.be/XdXHh1Thd58)</sup>

According to [the official product detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20151013074348/https://azpenpc.com/product/detail.php/id-8.html), the tablet supports MicroSD up to 32GB.

[image]